# Is it possible to have negative Z-spread for a corporate bond?

Tags: bond, spread

I have a 2 year maturity AA rated US corporate bonds, and I found that it has negative Z-spread, -0.00053.
Does it make sense or it's wrong?

Comment: Without any further information I think it’s probably wrong.  Also the fact you have included so many decimal  places and haven’t included any units (pct, bp) looks strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for an IG bond to be trading at a small negative Z-spread.

Z-spread is a spread to LIBOR. LIBOR is above treasury because it includes a tiny bit of "common banks" credit risk.

It's also possible that your bond has some features, such as collateral, that make the bond more valuable, but that the Z-spread calculation doen't take into account. Z-spread just looks at the cash flows if the bond does not default, not at probability of default and loss given default.